# Socket.io example, config.json what is it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter, socket.io

So on the socket.io website it gives an example on a streaming twitter posts and displaying certain ones using a filter. I understand that I need a config.json file but I don't know what it should contain. If someone could help me with replicating the simple example on socket.io that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a repo of that example https://github.com/sisardor/node-socket.io-example

and the `config.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "host":"localhost",
    "port":8080
}
```